# Close IOS native select box menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement in which i need to close the native select menu using javascript, i had tried for simulating javascript click events in body or anywhere outside like:

```
var body = docuement.querySelector('body')
body.click() // not working

var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown')
body.dispatchEvent(event) //not working
```

but its not working , below is the image of native select menu i am taking about

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out the solution

```
// select your dropdown element
// suppose dropdown element has id xyz

var dropdown= document.querySelector('#xyz');

// then fire the blur event

dropdown.blur();

// with above the native dropdown will go away
```